# Airflow & boto: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, airflow

I am using boto2 to access my S3 bucket, and I am having trouble getting consistent results with the Apache Airflow Scheduler.  I have a script getting my bucket from S3 and uploading a zip file to that bucket.  I have the script running on an Airflow scheduler with a bash operator.  The schedule seems to work fine when I am at the computer, or when I manually run the script.  I have noticed the script will throw a 403 Forbidden error when the computer has gone idle.  For example, I have my script running once a day, and will successfully execute my script using airflow during the week, and once the weekend starts the script will fail to run, and throw a 403 error.  Any idea why this behavior pattern is happening?  My aws account should have full access rights on S3.  And I have airflow running from a docker container.

Here is the function in my script accessing the bucket:

```
def upload_s3(string_passed):
    s3 = boto.connect_s3()
    aabucket = s3.get_bucket('bucketname',validate='False')
    k = Key(aabucket)
    k.key = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+str('.gz') #filename
    k.set_contents_from_string(string_passed) #send data to s3
    print("S3 UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL!")
```

Here is the dag config script I am running:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

schedule_interval="00 18 * * *"

args = {

    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(year=2017, month=03, day=21, hour=18 ,minute=00, second=00),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 4,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = 'appannie_bash_operator_v10',
    default_args = args,
    schedule_interval = schedule_interval
)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id = 'get_json',
    bash_command = 'python ~/appannie/appannie_scrape_update.py',
    dag=dag,
)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id = 'export_s3',
    bash_command = 'python --version',
    dag = dag,
)
t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

Here is the log error I receive:

```
[2017-04-04 21:50:28,996] {models.py:1219} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): get_json> on 2017-04-03 18:00:00
[2017-04-04 21:50:29,156] {bash_operator.py:55} INFO - tmp dir root location: 
/tmp
[2017-04-04 21:50:29,157] {bash_operator.py:64} INFO - Temporary script location :/tmp/airflowtmp5_nqrG//tmp/airflowtmp5_nqrG/get_json0aZng2
[2017-04-04 21:50:29,158] {bash_operator.py:65} INFO - Running command: python ~/appannie/appannie_scrape_update.py
[2017-04-04 21:50:29,162] {bash_operator.py:73} INFO - Output:
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,057] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - JSON DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFUL!
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,368] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,678] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - File "/usr/local/airflow/appannie/appannie_scrape_update.py", line 244, in <module>
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,679] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - upload_s3(x2)
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,680] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - File "/usr/local/airflow/appannie/appannie_scrape_update.py", line 41, in upload_s3
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,680] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - aabucket = s3.get_bucket('nixhydra-appannie',validate='False')
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,681] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 506, in get_bucket
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,681] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,682] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 539, in head_bucket
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,682] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - raise err
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,683] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,683] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - 
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,684] {bash_operator.py:80} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,685] {models.py:1286} ERROR - Bash command failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1245, in run
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 83, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
AirflowException: Bash command failed
[2017-04-04 21:51:06,686] {models.py:1298} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2017-04-04 21:51:07,699] {models.py:1327} ERROR - Bash command failed
[2017-04-04 21:53:18,231] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/appannie_bash_operator_v10.py
[2017-04-04 21:53:21,470] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/appannie_bash_operator_v10.py
[2017-04-04 21:53:21,515] {models.py:1196} INFO -
```

Comment: Did you pass the proper user environment in airflow required by your python script?

Comment: @mootmoot what do you mean by the user environment?  Would this be the dag config?

Comment: All task scheduler will load another shell to run those program. So if your program need explicit library path,etc. you must specify them.  However, Airflow seems has additional implementation to read credential when you use boto and boto3 : Please check this out and follow those links. Or post your question there https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-115

Comment: I have given my script the necessary credentials to access s3, and the script is able to run independently of airflow.